# Add large size images from gallery to my app

Tags: android, bitmap

My app is crashed while adding large size images from my device gallery to my app. I had gone through some solutions like resizing, scaling etc but it didn't work out.

Following code part is executed when I select an image from gallery

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, 
        Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent); 
        switch(requestCode) { 
            case REQ_CODE_PICK_IMAGE:
                if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){  
                        Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
                        String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
                        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                        cursor.moveToFirst();
                        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                        String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                        cursor.close();
                        //Convert Bitmap to Byte Array:-
                        Bitmap yourSelectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
                        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        yourSelectedImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                        byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
                        //Pass byte array into intent:-             
                        Intent intent = new Intent(UserAccount.this,RetrieveImage.class);
                        intent.putExtra("picture", byteArray);
                        startActivity(intent);
            } } }
```

RetrieveImage.java

```
         Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        byte[] byteArray = extras.getByteArray("picture");
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
        ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        img.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

How can I solve this problem.

Comment: Please post your logcat output

Answer (score 0):

Use this for Scaling :

```
Bitmap ThumbImage = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath), 
                    THUMBSIZE, THUMBSIZE);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 InputStream stream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);

 stream = ctx.getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
 Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream, null, options);
 stream.close();


 Use above to get bitmap image from image uri create your options.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
File f = new File("getfile from media");
        if(f.exists())
        {
            FileInputStream is = null;
            try {
                is = new FileInputStream(f);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                Log.d("error: ", String.format(
                "ShowPicture.java file[%s]Not Found", fileName));
                return;
            }   
            Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, null);                             
            pic.setImageBitmap(bm);

            }
```